# How to add callback to the view without making it recompose in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

When I am trying to do some small example of code displaying list of items, all my `ItemView`s recompose all the time, even if they don’t change. They recompose both when I add item to favourite and when I change order of list.

Whole code seems to be working when I remove callback:

```
IconToggleButton(
    checked = item.isFavorite,
    onCheckedChange = { }
)
```

My code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                MainView(ItemViewModel())
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun MainView(vm: ItemViewModel) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(
            count = vm.items.size,
            key = { idx -> vm.items[idx].hashCode() },
        ) { idx ->
            ItemView(
                item = vm.items[idx],
                modifier = Modifier.animateItemPlacement(),
                onFavoriteClick = vm::onFavoriteClick,
            )
        }
    }
}

class ItemViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var items = mutableStateListOf<Item>().apply {
        addAll(List(5) { Item(id = it.toString(), name = "Item $it") })
    }
 
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            delay(3000)
            items.clear()
            items.addAll(List(5) { Item(id = (4 - it).toString(), name = "Item ${4 - it}") )
        }
    }
 
    fun onFavoriteClick(item: Item) {
        val idx = items.indexOf(item)
        items[idx] = item.copy(isFavorite = !item.isFavorite)
    }
}
 
data class Item(
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val isFavorite: Boolean = false,
)
 
@Composable
fun ItemView(
    item: Item,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onFavoriteClick: (Item) -> Unit = {},
) {
    Row(modifier = modifier) {
        Text(text = item.name)
        IconToggleButton(
            checked = item.isFavorite,
            onCheckedChange = { onFavoriteClick(item) }
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.FavoriteBorder,
                contentDescription = null
            )
        }
    }
}
```

How to make this code works? I see that  `Text` and  `IconToggleButton` components recomposition is skipped but  `ItemView` is recomposed anyway.

Comment: `remember(item) { {onFavoriteClick(item)} }`

Comment: Thank you! So this is proper way to call my ItemView? With remember both on modifier and callback
`ItemView(
    item = vm.items[idx],

    modifier = remember { Modifier.animateItemPlacement() },
    onFavoriteClick = remember(vm) { vm::onFavoriteClick },
)
`

Comment: in cases when you don't pass any parameters, simply `onFavoriteClick = vm::onFavoriteClick` should be enough, as `vm` should be stable, as well as function reference. To make sure it stable, you should use `viewModel<ItemViewModel>()` instead of creating it manually - it's gonna create it and store during activity lifetime. `remember` for modifier is redundant too.